# Trouble in UITableView

Tags: ios, xml, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which uses `NSMutableArray` populated by parsing an xml file.

**Problem:** The data gets added to the array but is not visible in the `UITableView`.

**Sublist.h**

```
@interface SubList:UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *List1;
    NSXMLParser *xmlparser;
    NSURLConnection *conn;
    NSMutableData *webdata;
    NSString *FolderID;
    NSMutableArray *info;
    NSMutableArray *SubFolderData;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *info;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *SubFolderData;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *FolderID;
@property(nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UITableView *List1;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *theXML;
```

@end

**Sublist.m**

```
@implementation SubList

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES; 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initWithData];
    [self GetChilds:FolderID UserID:@"1"];
}

-(void)GetChilds:(NSString*)FolderIDRecvd UserID:(NSString*)userID
{
    FolderID=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", FolderIDRecvd];
    NSString *_UserID=@"1";

    NSString *soapMsg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'   xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><TreeDataSubFolder xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><FolderID>%@</FolderID><UserId>%@</UserId></TreeDataSubFolder></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>",FolderID,_UserID];


    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.5/interlogicsmobile/interlogics.asmx?op=TreeDataSubFolder"];
    xmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSMutableURLRequest *req=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMsg length]];

    [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [req addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/TreeDataSubFolder" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [req addValue:@"length" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];

    if(conn) {
        webdata=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)   response 
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response; 
    int responseStausCode = [httpResponse statusCode]; 
    [webdata setLength: 0]; 
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *) data 
{
    [webdata appendData:data];
}

-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didFailWithError:(NSError *) error 
{
    [webdata release];
    [connection release];
}

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection 
{
    theXML= [[NSString alloc] 
          initWithBytes: [webdata mutableBytes] 
          length:[webdata length] 
          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [theXML release];

    SubListParser *parserObjForData1=[[SubListParser alloc]init];
    SubFolderData=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]retain];
    SubFolderData=[parserObjForData1 UserXMLParser1:webdata];

    [connection release];
    [webdata release];
    [List1 reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return([SubFolderData count]/2);
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row]*2;
    static  NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.text = [SubFolderData objectAtIndex:row+1];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [SubFolderData objectAtIndex:row];
    }

       for (int i=0; i<=[SubFolderData count]; i++) {

        NSString *filename = [SubFolderData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSString *ext = [filename pathExtension];
        if ([ext isEqualToString:@"doc"] || [ext isEqualToString:@"DOC"]) {
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DOC.png"]];
        } else if ([ext isEqualToString:@"jpg"]|| [ext isEqualToString:@"JPG"]) {
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"JPG.png"]];
        }else if([ext isEqualToString:@"pdf"]|| [ext isEqualToString:@"PDF"]){
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PDF.png"]];
        }else if([ext isEqualToString:@""]){
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Folder2.png"]];
        }else if([ext isEqualToString:@"docx"]|| [ext isEqualToString:@"DOCX"]){
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DOCX.png"]];
        }else if([ext isEqualToString:@"TIF"]|| [ext isEqualToString:@"tif"]){
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TIFF.png"]];
        }else if([ext isEqualToString:@"png"]|| [ext isEqualToString:@"PNG"]){
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PNG.png"]];
        }else if([ext isEqualToString:@"gif"]|| [ext isEqualToString:@"GIF"]){
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GIF.png"]];
        }else if([ext isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]|| [ext isEqualToString:@"JPEG"]){
            [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"JPG.png"]];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

### EDIT

```
-(NSMutableArray *)UserXMLParser1:(NSData *)WebDataRecieved1
{
    NSXMLParser *xmlparser1=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:WebDataRecieved1];
    [xmlparser1 setDelegate:self];
    BOOL success=[xmlparser1 parse];
    NSLog(@"%i",success); return listset1;
}
```

Comment: 1. check if your delegates are set. 2.If they are called.

Comment: in .h you said to compiler this class with conform to delegate. But you need to set either by drag-drop or [tv setDelegate:self] etc

Comment: in viewDidLoad method

Comment: write a nslog in all the tableview delegate methods and check if it gets print.

Comment: Post some relevant code. i.e. XML Parsing code, where you are filling the `DataSource` Array.

Comment: HI @RANA try to set text for textlabel and detailed text label outiside cell creatin

Comment: i.e add these line outside {}cell.textLabel.text = [SubFolderData objectAtIndex:row+1];
    NSLog(@"Cell text :%@", [SubFolderData objectAtIndex:row+1]);
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [SubFolderData objectAtIndex:row];

Comment: @Viral check the sublist.m file

Comment: [self.tablename reloadData];   Write this in the end of connectionDidFinishLoading method

Comment: @Viral -(NSMutableArray *)UserXMLParser1:(NSData *)WebDataRecieved1{
 
 NSXMLParser *xmlparser1=[[NSXMLParser      alloc]initWithData:WebDataRecieved1];
 [xmlparser1 setDelegate:self];
 BOOL success=[xmlparser1 parse];
 NSLog(@"%i",success);
 return listset1;
   }

Comment: are you try with @MinkleGarg idea?

Comment: yes i have doesnt seem to work

Comment: i have two files a sublistParser and a Sublist file the Parsing of the data from the XML is done in the sublistParser file which has the UserXmlParser1 method defined in it which parses the data to the Sublist file through an array Listset1 which then should add data to subfolderData array.

Comment: @Viral I am just not getting it.

Answer (score 1):

You delegates are not entered, so you haven't set those, use;

```
[List1 setDelegate:self];
[List1 setDataSource:self];
```

in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I had done this earlier and it didnt work, i have done it again and it still doesnt work.

Comment: @RANA: Have you hooked the List1 to correct tableView. and use `@` to refer me, so that i get notified.

Comment: I dont have the reputation to tag you :D

Answer (score 1):

Hi RANA we don't know how ur doing parsing because u did not post any parser methods. But based on ur code i got something that is

1. The return type for this [parserObjForData1 UserXMLParser1:webdata]; is Array am i correct ?
2. If my guessing is correct try this

SubListParser *parserObjForData1=[[SubListParser alloc]init];

SubFolderData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[parserObjForData1 UserXMLParser1:webdata]];

instead of

```
 SubListParser *parserObjForData1=[[SubListParser alloc]init];
    SubFolderData=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    SubFolderData=[parserObjForData1 UserXMLParser1:webdata];
```

I hope it will help to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sublistparser.m file

```
#import "SubListParser.h"
 #import "DocumentManagementAppDelegate.h"

 @implementation SubListParser
  @synthesize mParserArray,ID,URL,SubjectType,Name;
  static int count = 1;


   -(NSMutableArray *)UserXMLParser1:(NSData *)WebDataRecieved1{

NSXMLParser *xmlparser1=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:WebDataRecieved1];
[xmlparser1 setDelegate:self];
BOOL success=[xmlparser1 parse];
NSLog(@"%i",success);
return listset1;

  }
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
NSLog(@"NSXMLParser ERROR: %@ - %@",  [parseError localizedDescription], [parseError   localizedFailureReason]);
 }

  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
   attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
 {  
currentElementValue =[elementName copy];
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"FileFolderDetails"]){
    item=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   Name=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    SubjectType=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    URL=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
   // NSLog(@"%@",Name);
}


//if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"FileFolderDetails"]) {
//  NSLog(@"Inside FolderName");
  //  SUBLIST=[[SubListParser alloc]init];
  //  SUBLIST=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Name"]; 

//}
 }

 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
//NSLog(@"%@",string);
if(count){
    listset1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];
    count=0;
    Urlarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];
}


if ([currentElementValue isEqualToString:@"Name"]) {
    [Name appendString:string];
    [listset1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Name]];
        //    NSLog(@"%@",listset1);
}

if ([currentElementValue isEqualToString:@"URL"]) {
    [URL appendString:string];
    [Urlarray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",URL]];
    NSLog(@"Url Array :%@",Urlarray);

}


 }
  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;
{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"FileFolderDetails"]){
[item setObject:Name forKey:@"Name"];
[item setObject:SubjectType forKey:@"Type"];
[item setObject:URL forKey:@"URL"];
[users addObject:item];
}


}


  @end
```

Comment: Hi RANA if you observe above code carefully you may find the issue that is see the below code - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
//NSLog(@"%@",string);
if(count){
    listset1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];
    count=0;
    Urlarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];
}


if ([currentElementValue isEqualToString:@"Name"]) {
    [Name appendString:string];
    [listset1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Name]];
        //    NSLog(@"%@",listset1);
}

Comment: If u see found characters method you are initialing the listset1 array inside that so obviously that array will get clear continuously so even if you add anything in that array it won't be add. Due to this only you are not getting the data in tableview. Now for avoding this what you have to do is you have to intiate the listset1 array in UserXMLParser1 method not in foundcharacters method.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Select your table view in the interface builder
- Select connection inspector
- connect datasource and delegate to files owner ..

Your table view connection should look like below image .

[image]

Add also check whether array is added before table view delegate is called .

Comment: I have the same connections in my xib file

Comment: place a break point at numberOfRowsInSection , log [SubFolderData count]/2,post the log message here....